# jQuery set attribute without value

Tags: jquery

I want do do this in jQuery:

```
<option value="test" selected>...</option>
```

But everything I've tried gives me:

```
<option value="test" selected="selected">...</option>
```

I have tried `.attr("selected", "")` as well as `.attr("selected", true)`, but they give the undesired `selected="selected"` result. How can I do this? Everything I've found on online suggests either the former or the latter of the above formats.

Comment: why are you even concerned about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about the attribute at all, you should be changing the **property**

```
$('option').prop('selected', true);
```

You can also set the selected option by just changing the value of the select (assuming it's not `multiple`)

```
$('select').val('test');
```

It doesn't matter what it looks like in the HTML, it's the representation in the DOM that matters, both for setting the option as selected and when submitting the form it's in.

---

FYI, `<option value="test" selected="selected">` is not undesireable at all, it's completely valid and what you'd generally want.

When the `selected` attribute is present, the option is selected, regardless of the attributes value, even if it's empty the option will be selected.

Attributes should have values though, so `selected="selected"` is fine, and even something like `selected="hello kitty"` would select the option, to unselect it you'd remove the attribute, but again, you should be changing the ***property!!!***

Comment: Yes, I tried this also, but for some reason it doesn't seem to make any difference. I don't get it. Why would `.attr` work but not `.prop`?

Comment: are you using latest jquery?

Comment: Well, first of all, both the HTML snippets you've posted in the question are valid, and generally you'd want the latter one, that's why you get that with `attr`. Secondly, as noted above, you should be changing the underlying property, not the attribute, but `prop` was added in jQuery 1.6, and hopefully you're using a newer version than that.

Comment: @adeneo, I understand that what you are suggesting is correct, but for some reason it isn't working for me. Surely there is an underlaying problem somewhere, so perhaps I have misidentified the issue. Regardless, I thank you. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: Start by opening the console (F12) and check for errors, and verify that you're using a current version of jQuery.